# How to redirect command output and error to two different files?

Tags: linux, io-redirection

I want to redirect output of a tar command to one file say, `out.log` and errors during execution should be redirected to another file for example, `error.log`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here you Go,

> tar command 2> error.log 1> out.log

**To append to the existing log**

> tar command 2>> error.log 1>> out.log

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` to redirect standard output, and `&2>` to redirect standard error. So in your example:

`tar whatever > out.log 2> error.log`